# Windows Mobile Hi-Res Designer in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-mobile, designer

Is it possible to do Windows Mobile development in Visual Studio (2008), where the Windows Mobile Forms designer appears in "hi-res" (VGA/>96 DPI), rather than the default lo-res view?

I'm using Resco controls, which have some built-in support for hi-res, but it's a little bit slow to develop any significant forms, because you don't know what it will look like until you run the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `FormFactor` property on your forms to something with "VGA" in it.